# Excel - Name Comparison

Tags: microsoft-excel

I read an answer from a post submitted five years ago.  In that post the individual was trying to compare the names in one spreadsheet with those in another spreadsheet and flag the differences.  In that case the first and last names were in two separate columns.  The poster identified the spreadsheets as F1 and F2.  The formula looked pretty straight forward, but my confusion was with the name of the spreadsheets.  Were they named that way for ease in setting up the formula?  I have my lists in two spreadsheets in one workbook—I can change the names on the spreadsheets if necessary.  Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Can you add a link to that other post and the formula you've been trying to your question please?

Comment: If you mean [this post](https://superuser.com/q/669610/534850), it seems to me that "F1" and "F2" were used as substitutes for the actual names, just to simplify the discussion (they say: "I have to sheets (say F1 and F2) .."), but that is just my speculation. I would not use such names for sheets, because of the similarity with cell identifiers. Too much shortening, just to avoid typing a few characters, is also not my primary reasons for name selection.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm assuming that both `Sheet 1` & `Sheet 2` has `First Names` are in Column `A` & `Second names` in Column `B`.*

Write this Array Formula in Cell `C2` of `Sheet 2` finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & fill down:

```
{=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2&B2,Sheet1!A$2:A$20&Sheet1!B$2:B$20,0)),"Duplicate.","Unique")}
```

**Note,** *adjust cell reference in formula as needed.*